# How to ignore EmitDefaultValue=false when serializing object fields and properties

Tags: json, serialization, json.net

I am attempting to serialize an object that has fields and properties decorated with [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
I cannot change those objects (no access to the source code) and I need to be able to serialize *all* fields and properties regardless of their value.
I tried using NullValueHandling.Include, but it made no difference. Is there a different setting that would allow me to instruct JSON.Net to serialize these properties?

Here is a very simple sample class (again, keep in mind that I cannot change this class in any way):

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
class SampleClass2
{
    public SampleClass2()
    {
        dow = daysOfWeek.Mon;
    }

    public enum daysOfWeek { Mon = 0, Tue = 1, Wed = 2, Thu = 3, Fri = 4, Sat = 5, Sun = 6 };

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public daysOfWeek dow;
}
```

And the code I am using to serialize it:

```
    public static void TestSerializeSampleClass2()
    {
        SampleClass2 sc2 = new SampleClass2();
        sc2.dow = SampleClass2.daysOfWeek.Mon;

        string json = "";

        Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings jss =
            new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings() { DefaultValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DefaultValueHandling.Include, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Include };
        // jss.DefaultValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DefaultValueHandling.Include;
        json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sc2, jss);
        Console.WriteLine(json);


        sc2.dow = SampleClass2.daysOfWeek.Tue;
        json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sc2, jss);
        Console.WriteLine(json);


        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

The output from running this:

{}
{"dow":1}

Zero (0) is the default C# value for enums, so when “dow” is set to “Mon” the serialized JSON is empty, while on the second attempt, using “Tue” I do get a value of 1.

I started going through the route of writing my own ContractResolver and had to give up. The original “GetSerializableMembers” code makes a lot of calls to internal methods and I would like to avoid having to override/copy so much of the code to my own project. I believe there might be a setting I am missing somewhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Gustavo

Comment: Why? It will deserialize correctly either way.

Comment: Not really. The object will not be consumed by C#. It is being deserialized by JavaScript control on a browser. The control is currently failing because it can't find the property. Thanks.

Comment: I tried an older version of the JSON.NET library (v3.5.0) and it actually ignores the EmitDefaultValue attribute. I am using that as a workaround for now. Support for EmitDefaultValue was added recently and I still have not been able to find a way to overwrite it without changing the class being serialized (which I am not allowed to do in this case).

Comment: Did you ever find a "Better" way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Can't DataContract Surrogates work here?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You can create a Surrogate class with whatever decorators you want (so without the EmitDefaultValue=false) and this should work without the need to replicate the whole initial class code.